# Swift Calculate Content Offset of item moving across visible screen

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I am re-creating the iPhone App Switcher page where the app's tab view size is based off the location of it on the visual screen (bigger on the right and smaller on the left). I I have an array of views within a scroll view. I want to set the size of each view (tab) based on the location / content offset of the view as it scrolls horizontally across the visible screen x-axis.

Here's my code in `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    tabViews.forEach { (tabView) in // tabViews: [UIView]
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

        // This should be a value between 0 and 1
        var screenOffsetX = tabView.convert(CGPoint(x: tabView.frame.minX, y: 0),to: view).x
        let maxValue: CGFloat = screenWidth / 8 // Max value is 1 + 1/8 scale size
        if screenOffsetX > maxValue { // Set max scale
            screenOffsetX = min(screenOffsetX, maxValue)
        }
        let minValue: CGFloat = 0
        if screenOffsetX < minValue { // Set min scale
            screenOffsetX = max(screenOffsetX, minValue)
        }

        let scaleAmount: CGFloat = 1 + (screenOffsetX / screenWidth)
        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleAmount, y: scaleAmount)
        tabView.transform = scaleTransform
    }
}
```

I think the math is off. I don't think the abcd.convert(point: ) is returning the correct content offset on the visual screen. Here's an image of the scroll view with views (tabs):

[image]

Each view should be slightly bigger on the right side of the screen and smaller on the left.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you just use `scrollView.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 100` to get a percentage? and then for min and max size just check `if < minValue {....}   if > maxValue {....}`

Comment: What is the average value of scaleAmount when you are scrolling? 
Can you verify if setting a custom value on  tabView.transform works?
For example: tabView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)

Comment: @Waylan Sands close! This will set the size based off the content offset of the scroll view but I want to set it based off the content offset of the main view that is the size of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabView.convert` won't return values between 0...1 for sure - it just translates a point to a different view coordinates.

Also it should be `scrollView.convert`, not `tabView.convert`.

Those checks can be simplified:

```
if screenOffsetX > maxValue { // Set max scale
   screenOffsetX = min(screenOffsetX, maxValue)
}
```

There is no point of doing `min` after you already confirmed that maxValue is smaller. You either do:

```
if screenOffsetX > maxValue { // Set max scale
   screenOffsetX = maxValue
}
```

or

```
screenOffsetX = min(screenOffsetX, maxValue)
```

I am not sure what is the usage in your code for maxValue and minValue, but if you want to scale things based on their position, I would suggest doing this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        tabViews.forEach { tabView in // tabViews: [UIView]
            let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            var screenOffsetX = scrollView.convert(CGPoint(x: tabView.frame.minX, y: 0), to: view).x
            var screenOffsetPercentage = screenOffsetX / screenWidth
            let minValue: CGFloat = 0.5
            let maxValue: CGFloat = 1
            let scaleAmount = minValue + (maxValue - minValue) * screenOffsetPercentage
            let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleAmount, y: scaleAmount)
            tabView.transform = scaleTransform
        }
    }
```

You will have to adapt it to your idea, but as a start it scales from 1.0 scale at right side, to 0.5 scale at the left side.

Results looks like: https://media.giphy.com/media/m5KSgIInJmGjEHLZXb/giphy.gif

Comment: You are a genius! You are amazing!!!! You have no idea how long I've tried getting this! Thank you!!

Comment: you know how the iPhone app switcher pages has the app tabs approach an asymptote / get closer to each as they near 0... any idea how you would add that piece?

Comment: @Ryan I think the best approach will be to use `scrollView.contentOffset.x` and position each element based scroll offset. You will have to calculate position of each element based on offset and index of element. That will also allow you to easily fade them out and in based on their position.

Comment: I posted a new question on the frame problem.There's 50 points in it for you if you can figure out a solution!